# rails query multiple tables with has many though relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

Hello i am looking for a way to query in these 4 tables to get the only products that matches users selected categories in rails 4.

Rails Models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories, through: :user_categories
  has_many :user_categories
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories, through: :product_categories
  has_many :product_categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :products
end

class UserCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
end

class ProductCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Table structure

```
products             
+---------------+      
| id | name     |   
+---------------+ 
| 1  | mouse    | 
| 2  | keyboard | 
| 3  | iphone 6 | 
+---------------+ 

categories
+---------------+
| id | name     |
+---------------+
| 1  | computer |
| 2  | mobile   |
+---------------+

users
+-----------+
| id | name |
+-----------+
| 1  | foo  |
| 2  | bar  |
+-----------+

product_categories
+------------------+
| id | p_id | c_id |
+------------------+
| 1  |   1  |   1  |
| 2  |   3  |   2  |
+------------------+

user_categories
+------------------+
| id | u_id | c_id |
+------------------+
| 1  |   1  |  1   |
+------------------+
```

Comment: it's easier if you post models with associations

Comment: i just updated my question.

Comment: Try my answer @r1400304

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
@user_categories_ids = User.first.categories.map(&:id)

Product.includes(:categories).where(categories: { id: @user_categories_ids })
```

This should work if you've set up your associations correctly.

If you're not using the category association later on, performance wise it would be best to use a `joins()` or `joins().distinct()` instead of `includes()`

Example for joins:

```
Product.joins(:categories).where(categories: { id: @user_categories_ids })
```

If you want unique results

```
Product.joins(:categories).where(categories: { id: @user_categories_ids }).distinct # .uniq should also work I guess.
```

Comment: i tried that works but if you can give me example using joins that would be great thanks

Comment: You're welcome, I spotted and corrected a small mistake, you should use includes if you're using the categories in the product loop